# Why isn't text-justify: distribute working in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

In Firefox, the below CSS works:

```css
.fill-space {
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: distribute; /*This property is not working */
    text-align-last: center;
}
```

But it's not working in Chrome. How can I get it working in Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-justify), `text-justify: distribute` is deprecated:

> *distribute*: Exhibits the same behaviour as `inter-character`; this value is kept for backwards compatibility.

Try `text-justify: inter-character` instead.

Comment: MDN says that in Chrome, it must be enabled by user, so you can't rely on it.

Comment: @PoulBak Ah yeah, good catch. Well, in that case there's no reliable solution for OP.

Answer (score 0):

was looking to do this also. Details here from W3 - basically its not been rolled out yet, looks to be behind experimental features and needs to be enabled on chrome.... but is available on IE!!!!?????

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-justify.asp

*This feature is behind the Enable Experimental Web Platform Features preference (needs to be set to Enabled). To change preferences in Chrome: type in "chrome://flags" in the Chrome browser. To change preferences in Opera: type in "flags" in the Opera browser.